# The unary increment operator in pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, increment, operator-keyword

this is my first post.

I have this function for reversing a string in C
that I found.

```
    void reverse(char* c) {
        if (*c != 0) {
            reverse(c + 1);
        }
        printf("%c",*c);
    }
```

It works fine but if I replace:

```
reverse(c + 1);
```

with:

```
reverse(++c);
```

the first character of the original string is truncated. My question is why would are the
statements not equivalent in this instance?

Thanks

Comment: It would work fine if you changed the `*c` in the `printf` call to `*--c`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `c + 1` doesn't change the value of `c`, and `++c` does.

Answer (score 4):

Let's expand on Fred's answer just a bit.  `++c` is equivalent to `c = c+1`, not `c+1`.  If you replace the line `reverse(c+1)` with `reverse(++c)`, then `c` is changed.  This doesn't matter as far as the recursive call is concerned (why?) but means `c` is pointing somewhere new in the `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

`c + 1` does not alter `c`,

`++c` increments c and then uses the new value in your replaced recursive call, `reverse(++c)`

Answer (score 1):

As noted, `++c` changes the value of `c` but `c+1` does not.

This does not matter in the recursive call itself: `reverse(c+1)` and `reverse(++c)` will pass the same value to `reverse`; the difference happens when you use `c` in a `printf` after the recursive call -- in the `++c` case, the value of `c` has been changed by the time you reach the `printf`.